# Can the lifecycleScope for the current Activity be injected into a non-Activity class using Dagger?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, dagger-2, coroutinescope

Here's an extremely simplified example:

```
class MyActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {
}

@ActivityScope // Dagger scope
class Foo @Inject constructor(
    private val bar: Bar,
    @Named("MAIN_SCOPE") private val scope: CoroutineScope,
) {
    private val myJob = scope.launch {
        bar.myFlow?.collect {
            // process result
        }
    }

    fun cleanUp() {
        myJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way to approach this. Again, this is a simplified example of what I have. I realize an obvious alternative would be to pass the scope from `MyActivity` to `Foo` - let's just say that isn't practical in this case.

Is there a way to use Dagger to inject the `lifecycleScope` from the current `Activity` - `MyActivity` in this case, but it could be a different one at runtime - into `Foo`? Then I couldn't need to explicitly cancel the `Job`; I could just make use of the injected scope, assured that coroutine `Job`s would shut down when the `Activity` shut down.

Comment: What about creating a dagger component with a builder or a factory and inject the `lifecycleScope` into a di graph using `@BindsInstance`? Then `Foo` can be injected into the activity and the scope would be launched at the creation of `Foo`.

Comment: @art I'm unclear on how to instantiate an `Activity` that way, retrieve the `lifecycleScope` from it, and then inject that scope into `Foo`. I'm not sure that's possible, but if there's a web page explaining it, I'd love the link! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how dagger component can be created:

```
@Component // or can be @Subcomponent
@ActivityScope
internal interface MyActivityComponent {

    fun inject(activity: MyActivity)

    @Component.Factory // or @Subcomponent.Factory respectively
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance activity: MyActivity): MyActivityComponent
    }
}
```

And here is activity and `Foo` class:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    internal lateinit var foo: Foo

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        DaggerMyActivityComponent.factory() // or take factory from parent component
            .create(this)
            .inject(this)

        foo.launchFoo()
    }
}

@ActivityScope
internal class Foo @Inject constructor(
    private val activity: MyActivity,
    private val bar: Bar,
) {
    private val activityScope: CoroutineScope
        get() = activity.lifecycleScope

    fun launchFoo() {
        activityScope.launch {
            bar.myFlow?.collect {
                 // process result
            }
        }
    }
}
```